# Prove that $f$ is a polynomial if $\int_{\partial(B(0,1))}\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n(a)}}=0$ for al $a$.

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f$ be a holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$, a unit disk centered at $0$.
Suppose that for each $a\in B(0,1)\subseteq\mathbb{C}$, there exists $n(a)\in\mathbb{N}$ such that 
$$\int_{\partial(B(0,1))}\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n(a)}}=0$$.

Prove that $f$ is a polynomial.

Comment: If $n(a)$ are the same for every $a$, that means $f^{(n-1)}(a)=0$. So, this case it is obvious. For this case, I know that $f^{(n(a)-1)} (a)=0$. But $n(a)$ depends on $a$. I was thinking about identity theorem. But I don't know how to apply here.

Comment: It is holomorphic on the complex plane. I am sorry. I edited the question.

Comment: In that case you can just say "Let $f$ be an entire function, blahblah...". Try to prove the set of zeros of $f^{(n)}$ has a limit point in $B$ for some $n$.

Comment: @QiyuWen But $n$ depends on $a$.

Comment: The analogous real analysis problem is [a bit harder](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Archives/Mathematics/2010_November_13).

Answer (score 2):

**hint:**
Let $ A_n = \{ z | \int_{\partial(B(0,1))}\frac{f(z)}{(z-a)^{n}}=0\}    $, then $A_n$ is closed and $\bigcup_{n\geq 0} A_n= B(0,1)$.